# How to generate close colors to a rgb value?

Tags: python, colors

I'd like to be able to generate multiple colors close to one RGB color as the schema below.

[image]

Here's the what I've made using Python :

```
def similarColors(rgb, loop=6):
    difference = 30
    colors = []
    for i in range(loop):
        red = rgb[0]
        red_highest = red + difference
        red_lowest = red - difference
        red = randint(red_lowest, red_highest)

        green = rgb[1]
        green_highest = green + difference
        green_lowest = green - difference
        green = randint(green_lowest, green_highest)

        blue = rgb[2]
        blue_highest = blue + difference
        blue_lowest = blue - difference
        blue = randint(blue_lowest, blue_highest)

        colors.append([red, green, blue])
    return colors

palette = similarColors([244, 83, 28])
```

**Question:** I feel like I'm overcomplicating things with this method is there a way to make the code above cleaner and shorter?

I'd like to avoid doing the same process for each color (red, blue, green) separately, I am also not sure if this method is really precise for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I've added a new version to my answer that (partially) compensates for the fact that the human visual system isn't equally sensitive to red, green, and blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can condense that code quite a bit by looping over the RGB components. However, there's a bug in your current algorithm: it can produce color channel values that are < 0 or > 255, so we need to fix that.

```
from random import randint

def similarColors(rgb, loop=6):
    colors = []
    delta = 30
    for i in range(loop):
        new_rgb = [randint(max(0, x - delta), min(x + delta, 255)) for x in rgb]  
        colors.append(new_rgb)                
    return colors

colors = similarColors([244, 83, 28])
print(colors)
```

**typical output**

```
[[249, 75, 28], [226, 111, 34], [235, 85, 46], [228, 66, 28], [244, 62, 8], [233, 102, 21]]
```

---

You said: "I am also not sure if this method is really precise for what I'm trying to achieve". I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve, but one problem I can see is that the human visual system is not equally sensitive to R, G, & B. So a change by a given amount in one channel will not have the same effect as the same change in another channel. To deal with that properly you need to work in a colorspace that's more closely aligned to the human visual system, eg [Lab color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space). However, we can get a reasonable approximation by using scaling factors on the channel deltas.

The Wikipedia article on [Grayscale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) provides a formula that can be used to compute the luminance of a RGB color:

```
y = 0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B
```

This formula was used in analog NTSC & PAL television.

Here's a version of the above code that uses those scaling factors. We divide our base `delta` by those scaling factors, so the blue delta is the largest & the green delta is smallest, because the eye is most sensitive to green and least sensitive to blue.

```
def similarColors(rgb, loop=6):
    colors = []
    delta = 10
    deltas = [round(delta / u) for u in (0.299, 0.587, 0.114)]
    for i in range(loop):
        new_rgb = [randint(max(0, x - delta), min(x + delta, 255)) 
            for x, delta in zip(rgb, deltas)]
        colors.append(new_rgb)
    return colors

colors = similarColors([244, 83, 28])
print(colors)
```

**typical output**

```
[[236, 84, 65], [233, 74, 78], [226, 93, 73], [249, 88, 89], [240, 84, 40], [226, 75, 22]]
```

To make that code more efficient, since we're using a fixed base `delta` we could pre-compute the `deltas` array, rather than re-computing it each time we call `similarColors`.

Comment: Now make it in place, and I'd say it's even easier - no return value, and applying this on every pixel of a picture automatically alters the picture

Comment: @Sanitiy Every Python function returns something: `None` is returned if there's no object explicitly returned. Sure, the function could accept a list arg and we could extend that with the new color list. That'd be better than extending a global `colors` list. I don't know what you mean exactly by "applying this on every pixel of a picture" because `similarColor` takes a single color value as its arg and returns 6 color values.

Comment: For the precision I meant that if the color is orange, it'll show shades of oranges instead of other colors.

Comment: @Lindow Ah, ok. The new version is a _bit_ better in that respect. But we can do better if we work in the HSV or HLS color space. By making the hue delta small the new colors will have a similar hue to the original color. Take a look at the [`colorsys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/colorsys.html) module, which has the conversion functions you'll need, try to code something, and if you get stuck, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to copy-paste each color, you could use a for loop like this:

```
def similarColors(rgb, loop=6, difference=30):
    colors = []
    for _ in range(loop):
        color = []
        for curr_color in rgb:
            color.append(randint(curr_color - difference, curr_color + difference))
        colors.append(color)

    return colors
```

Notice I also put `difference` in the parameters.

And there's a bug where the rgb parts can be < 0 or > 255, you could fix that by using `max(0, min(255, randint(curr_color - difference, curr_color + difference)))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `numpy`, a **much more compact solution** is this:

```
import numpy as np

def similarColors(rgb, loop=6):
    delta = 30
    origClrs = np.tile(np.array(rgb), (loop, 1))
    randOffsets = np.random.randint(-delta, delta, size=(loop, 3))
    return origClrs + randomOffsets
```